# C++: Looking for a concise solution to replace a set of characters in a std::string with a specific character

Tags: c++, string

Suppose I have the following:

```
std::string some_string = "2009-06-27 17:44:59.027";
```

The question is: Give code that will replace all instances of "-" and ":" in some_string with a space i.e. " "

I'm looking for a simple one liner (if at all possible)

Boost can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Boost regex to do it. Something like this:

```
e = boost::regex("[-:]");
some_string = regex_replace(some_string, e, " ");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
replace_if( some_string.begin(), some_string.end(), boost::bind( ispunct<char>, _1, locale() ), ' ' );
```

One line and not n^2 running time or invoking a regex engine ;v) , although it is a little sad that you need boost for this.

Comment: Note that this will replace all punctuation characters, not just ':' and '-'.  `ispunct<char>` should be replaced with a function that does what is specified.

Comment: replace( some_string.begin(), some_string.end(), ':', ' ' );

replace( some_string.begin(), some_string.end(), '-', ' ' );

Comment: +1 for the note about the n^2 running time and/or use of regex engines for other answers.  I know that thinking about performance is out-of-fashion, but if one doesn't care about performance, why the hell would they bother with C++?

Answer (score 5):

Boost has a string algorithm library that seems to fly under the radar:

[String Algorithm Quick Reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/string_algo/quickref.html)

There is a regex based version of replace, similar to post 1, but I found `find_format_all` better performance wise. It's a one-liner to boot:

```
find_format_all(some_string,token_finder(is_any_of("-:")),const_formatter(" "));
```

Answer (score 4):

I would just write it like this:

```
for (string::iterator p = some_string.begin(); p != some_string.end(); ++p) {
    if ((*p == '-') || (*p == ':')) {
        *p = ' ';
    }
}
```

Not a concise one-liner, but I'm pretty sure it will work right the first time, nobody will have any trouble understanding it, and the compiler will probably produce near-optimal object code.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/find_first_of

```
string some_string = "2009-06-27 17:44:59.027";
size_type found = 0;
while ((found = str.find_first_of("-:", found)) != string::npos) {
    some_string[found] = ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [&](char c) -> bool {
    return c == '-' || c == '.';
}, ' ');
```

This is 1 liner using C++11. If not use functors:

```
replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), CanReplace, ' ');

typedef string::iterator Iterator;

bool CanReplace(char t)
{
    return t == '.' || t == '-';
}
```